# How do I add text to an output file?

Tags: shell, scripting, grep, whois

I have a script for doing whois lookups:

```
#!/bin/bash
for domain in `cat /Users/jason/Desktop/letters.txt `; do
  echo $domain  >> /Users/jason/Desktop/whois-results.txt  whois $domain | grep "Expiry date"  >> /Users/jason/Desktop/whois-results.txt
done
```

This reads a text file of domain names and does a whois search

The result is:

> ```
>         Expiry date:  11-Jun-2016
>         Expiry date:  10-Jun-2024
>         Expiry date:  19-Aug-2016
>         Expiry date:  10-Jun-2015
>         Expiry date:  12-Jun-2016
>         Expiry date:  19-Aug-2016
>         Expiry date:  10-Jun-2016
> ```

What I want is:
 Expiry date:  11-Jun-2016

> ```
>   a.co.uk       Expiry date:  10-Jun-2024
>   b.co.uk       Expiry date:  19-Aug-2016
>   c.co.uk       Expiry date:  10-Jun-2015
>   d.co.uk       Expiry date:  12-Jun-2016
>   e.co.uk       Expiry date:  19-Aug-2016
>   f.co.uk       Expiry date:  10-Jun-2016
> ```

In other words I just want to add the $domain variable to start of each line.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

add a `-n` switch to have `echo` omit  the newline and then do your `whois` query:

```
#!/bin/bash
for domain in `cat /Users/jason/Desktop/letters.txt `
do
  echo -n "$domain  "  >> /Users/jason/Desktop/whois-results.txt  
  whois $domain | grep "Expiry date"  >> /Users/jason/Desktop/whois-results.txt
done
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not seem to help, I still don't get the domain listed (sorry this was not clear before hand). What I would like is:  f.co.uk       Expiry date:  10-Jun-2016 and not just Expiry date:  10-Jun-2016 .

Comment: Ignore my last. I had commented out the echo! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Taking things a little further, I have found that if I run this script, a number of the lookup do not report anything back. I am guessing that it is running too quickly. What is the best way of putting a short pause in? Sample output below:

a.ukb.uk        Expiry date:  11-Jun-2016
c.uk        Expiry date:  10-Jun-2024
d.uk        Expiry date:  19-Aug-2016
e.ukf.ukg.ukh.uki.ukj.ukk.ukl.ukm.ukn.uko.uk
p.uk        Expiry date:  10-Jun-2016
q.ukr.uk        Expiry date:  19-Aug-2016
s.uk        Expiry date:  10-Jun-2015
t.uk        Expiry date:  10-Jun-2024
u.ukv.ukw.ukx.uky.uk